# How do I cast from a pointer to an int?

Tags: c++, c, turtle-graphics

I am trying to return an int from a pointer but keeping getting an error messages 'cast from pointer to integer of different size'. The section of code is below. I think the problem might be that the functions that var_num calls are all void but ideally if I can get away without changing all of them (and their subsequent functions) that would be much easier. Thanks!

```
int var_num(Prog *ptr)
{
   if(!isdigit(ptr->words[ptr->current_line][0])) {
      ptr->current_var = ptr->vars[var_instruction(ptr)];
   }
   else {
      num_instruction(ptr);
   }

   return (int)ptr;
}
```

Comment: If you just want the function to return a Prog pointer, why declare it as int ?

Comment: The return value from `var_instruction()` is being used as an array index, so it can't return `void` - so, contrary to your description, all function called do not return `void`.   Anyway, you haven't specified what the caller will do with the returned `int`  - which will affect how (if at all) it makes sense to convert the pointer to an `int`.    If the caller, for some reason, tries to convert the returned `int` back to the pointer, then it may fail - pointers are not guaranteed to survive a round-trip (pointer to `int` and back to pointer) unchanged.

Comment: @CDummy Can you include the client-side code?

Comment: Post an [mcve].

Comment: Sorted now, thank you everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `Prog` is some kind of `struct` or a `class`. In either case it is an object that is much more complicated than a simple variable and converting it into a different type is not straight forward. At least the compiler can't do it by itself, because it's ambiguous.

The problem is, that the compiler can type cast `float` into an `int` for example, but converting `class Student` into a `class Car` cannot be done without you explicitly defining how that works.

If `Prog` contains some kind of attribute which you want to return (which I will call `attribute` in the example below), this is what you need to do:

```cpp
return ptr->attribute;
```

And if that attribute is of type different than `int` but is a [primitive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)) type, you can then type cast it like that.

```cpp
return (int)ptr->attribute;
```

Comment: And if you do want me to give you an exact solution (non attribute based), it might be worthwhile to share the `Prog` type is (like it's definition).

Comment: The question isn’t about converting a `Prog` **object** to an `int`; it’s about converting a `Prog*` (a **pointer**) to an `int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure. His function is called `var_num` not `var_address`.

Comment: But you are correct, the question can mean that as well.

Comment: @ItayGrudev Thanks! My question is about Prog* to int but i believe i have fixed it now. Thanks so much :)